# What are some free islamic counselling websites?

Tags: practical-islam

Recently I have undergone severe hardships and trials , and now I am feeling depressed and suicidal.

I know I am not supposed to kill myself because its a great sin. I feel depressed, deeply embarrassed, worthless, sad and I feel like I shouldn't have existed.

I know this isn't a counselling website, I am looking for one but I can't find one. I am in desperate need of consolation and advice.

I visited some online counselling websites but all of them involve payments which I am afraid I can't do because I am a child. I can't go and visit a physical counselor due to the covid situation in my country. I don't wont to ask my parents or (commit a sin) by without permission using their bank account to pay for online counselling.

I feel like I am stuck in a cage with no door(solution) out to my problems.

Hence I humbly ask whether my dear Brothers and sisters can help me in this regard to find a FREE counselling website. Its better if its an Islamic one but a non Islamic one is also ok but it should be free.

Jazakallahu Khair

Comment: Salam and weclome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Answer (score 1):

The one website that I would recommend would be IslamQnA, but I also recommend u talk to the sheikh of your local masjid (if they are open), or write to Sheikh Asim Al-Hakeem. Also strongly recommended is praying Istikhara. That always gives the solution. Talk to Allah Azwajal one-on-one, as if He (Azwajal) is sitting in front of you. Do this in private, and pour your heart out. Cry if you feel like doing so, but just be sure that you are saying. Refer to Him (Azwajal) by his attributes, like Ar-Rahman, Ar-Raheem, Al-Ghafur, Al-Ghafar etc. Believe me, it always always helps

Hope this answers your question.

Assalamualaikum Wa Rahmatullah Hi Wa Barakatahu.